# Checkboxes on form checked based on db query, not to be reset if validation fails

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form for users to update areas (up to 4) they wish to do services in. The form allows users to update their service areas in the db. Using `strpbrk()` I can successfully get their current areas checked when the page loads, but if the form validation fails the original checkboxes become re-checked. The form contains 132 areas.

Query return: `$row['location'] = "cityone.city two."`

Form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Accomack" name="T_ordernum[Accomack]" <?php if(isset($_POST['T_ordernum']) && is_array($_POST['T_ordernum']) && in_array('Accomack', $_POST['T_ordernum'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /> 
<label>Accomack</label><br/>

//repeated for all 132 areas
```

I've done this on other forms... where the user can see and update their info, and their edits are echoed if validation fails, but not from an array. Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit lengthy, but I got it. I place the query results into an array with `explode()`, and check if areas are in the array with `in_array()`:

```
$z = explode('.',$row['territories']);
if (in_array("Accomack",$z)){$z1 = "checked";}
if (in_array("Albemarle",$z)){$z2 = "checked";}
if (in_array("Alexandria",$z)){$z3 = "checked";}
// continue for remaining areas
```

I moved the `PHP` from the form inputs to the `POST` validation:

```
if(isset($_POST['T_ordernum']) && is_array($_POST['T_ordernum']) && in_array('Accomack', $_POST['T_ordernum'])){$z1 = "checked";}else{$z1 = '';}$_POST['T_ordernum'])){$z1 = "checked";}else{$z1 = '';}
if(isset($_POST['T_ordernum']) && is_array($_POST['T_ordernum']) && in_array('Albemarle', $_POST['T_ordernum'])){$z2 = "checked";}else{$z2 = '';}
if(isset($_POST['T_ordernum']) && is_array($_POST['T_ordernum']) && in_array('Alexandria', $_POST['T_ordernum'])){$z3 = "checked";}else{$z3 = '';}
//continue for remaining areas
```

And echo "checked" or '' into the inputs as appropriate:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Accomack" class="other" name="T_ordernum[Accomack]" <?php echo $z1;?> />
  <label class="left">Accomack</label><br/> 
<input type="checkbox" value="Albemarle" class="other" name="T_ordernum[Albemarle]" <?php echo $z2;?> />
  <label class="left">Albemarle</label><br/> 
<input type="checkbox" value="Alexandria" class="other" name="T_ordernum[Alexandria]" <?php echo $z3;?> />
  <label class="left">Alexandria</label><br/>
//continue for remaining areas
```

:D